# hive create view problem: internally casting numbers to something else

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm facing an issue in hive while creating view from a partitioned table. If I use the command below:

```
create view test_view as select * from table where and year=2000 and month=01 and day=02;
```

The view gets created but the below selection results in 0 records:

```
select count(*) from test_view where day='02';
```

Whereas, the below selection will work just what it's meant to do:

```
select count(*) from test_view where day='2';
```

The following command also gives the count(*) result properly:

```
select count(*) from test_view where day=2;
```

The important thing here is that `day=02` is a physical partition in the actual table, which is fine to the understanding. It's somehow the view creation is interpreting the input integers.

Anyone got any ideas on this?

Comment: what are the datatypes of the columns in the input table and the view?

Comment: The columns' data types remain the same, of the partitions as well (it's string type here, all of them).